# Is there something like a observer-node?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,

I am having the problem that once in a while some of my nodes randomly die due to hardware issues (overheating, miserable cable connection, problems in usb_read/write errors, etc.) that can't be faced by me.

I would like to know if I can create some sort of **observer-node**, that **listens to dying nodes and can thus initiate some recovery behavior**.
This is pretty important in my case, as sometimes my camera-node dies which leads to the situation, that the robot doesn't have any clue where it's located at.

If I had this observing node I could most likely manage the situation properly, without having to reboot everything.

I am really looking forward to your replies.

Best regards, Till

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273598/is-there-something-like-a-observer-node?/) by [Till Chima](https://answers.ros.org/users/32183/till-chima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-10-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-10-20**:
Do you just want to restart the node? In this case, check launch-files and especially the respawn-parameter.

**Comment by [Till Chima](https://answers.ros.org/users/32183/till-chima/) on 2017-10-20**:
The respawn flag won't work, as some specific actions have to be triggered before the node can restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could implement a central node that uses [bonds](http://wiki.ros.org/bond) to get a notification if one of the other nodes dies.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Till Chima](https://answers.ros.org/users/32183/till-chima/) on 2017-10-20**:
Perfect!
Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was hoping to find!